# Unable to Build Android's HelloWorld in RenderScript

Tags: android, renderscript

I am trying to build one of the RenderScript examples in the android/sdk/samples.
I've tried HelloWorld and Balls examples, but the application is force closing

```
05-11 15:25:44.670: WARN/bcc(14985): Unable to open /data/data/com.android.rs.helloworld/cache/@com.android.rs.helloworld:raw@helloworld.oBCC in read mode.  (reason: No such file or directory)
05-11 15:25:44.670: ERROR/bcc(14985): Unable to readBC, bitcode=0x17d3f8, size=1068
05-11 15:25:44.670: DEBUG/StopWatch(14985): StopWatch bcc: PrepareExecutable time (us): 1551 
05-11 15:25:44.670: ERROR/RenderScript(14985): bcc: FAILS to prepare executable
05-11 15:25:44.670: DEBUG/RenderScript(14985): >>>> ~ScriptC  bccDisposeScript(0x17d8f0)
05-11 15:25:44.670: ERROR/RenderScript(14985): rsAssert failed: !mUserRefCount, in frameworks/base/libs/rs/rsObjectBase.cpp at 63
05-11 15:25:44.670: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(14985): Shutting down VM
05-11 15:25:44.670: WARN/dalvikvm(14985): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4017e760)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.rs.helloworld/com.android.rs.helloworld.HelloWorld}: android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985): Caused by: android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at android.renderscript.ScriptC.(ScriptC.java:60)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at com.android.rs.helloworld.ScriptC_helloworld.(ScriptC_helloworld.java:32)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at com.android.rs.helloworld.HelloWorldRS.initRS(HelloWorldRS.java:46)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at com.android.rs.helloworld.HelloWorldRS.init(HelloWorldRS.java:37)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at com.android.rs.helloworld.HelloWorldView.ensureRenderScript(HelloWorldView.java:44)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at com.android.rs.helloworld.HelloWorldView.(HelloWorldView.java:33)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at com.android.rs.helloworld.HelloWorld.onCreate(HelloWorld.java:33)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
05-11 15:25:44.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14985):     ... 11 more
05-11 15:25:44.680: WARN/ActivityManager(130):   Force finishing activity com.android.rs.helloworld/.HelloWorld
```

I am attempting to build on the Xoom running 3.0.1.
Can anyone please confirm if you are able to install a RenderScript example?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having this problem with a Galaxy Tab 10.1v too. With every sample I tried, it crashed in a similar way you posted. Have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an acknowledged problem with the compiler that prevented any of the samples from running. It was addressed [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8025f56c4240cc4e?pli=1).

The workaround provided by the android team is to replace your platform-tools directory with the one from a previous release which uses the compiler from 3.0.

This fix worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm... This big yellow warning just popped up telling me this is not a discussion forum and I MUST ANSWER THE QUESTION! But since no one (including myself) really knows anything about Renderscript, I feel compelled to offer some assistance. And also because Google specifically points to StackOverflow as an Android resource. So apologies to the administrators!

Anyway, I've successfully run all the samples in Eclipse but NOT with the emulator. The emulator (at least on my machine) is hideously slow. I bought a Xoom and it's been pretty easy to get all the samples to run on it.

So if you're using Eclipse and an actual Xoom (not the emulator) then I suggest starting from scratch with a fresh Eclipse installation and a fresh Android SDK installation. And make sure you use the "New Android Project" to import the samples. There's a selection somewhere in the wizard that specifically addresses importing a sample.