# Neither files in bin\rsLibs nor in bin\rsObj - Android renderscript compilation error?

Tags: android, compilation, android-support-library, renderscript

As mentioned in the title, there are neither *.o nor *.so files in the projects dir. Strange enough, the *.d files are inside. In eclipse it says that the belonging .exe files could not open e.g. the *.o file. When I'm deleting the error message and debug the app I'll get an error "loading of scriptC script failed" similar to this one: [Unable to Build Android's HelloWorld in RenderScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971356/unable-to-build-androids-helloworld-in-renderscript)

After some research I finally found out that .o is an object file and .so has something do to with the libraries, so actually renderscript support library should have been created them. Which is obviously not the case...

Now I did the following:I found a sample project on github using the support library. In this project I found all the relevant files. Therefore, I bound this project in to eclipse. After cleaning it and trying to start it, suddenly the named files disappeared again! My guess is, that it could be a compilation bug, which its why I'd like to address especially the renderscript team. Nevertheless, I'd be very thankful for every advises!

What can I do?

Here are the error messages:

> Error executing Renderscript: Return code -1073741511 ColorChange line 1 Android AIDL Problem
>
> [2014-01-06 20:45:09 - HelloCompute] C:\android_sdk_windows\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: cannot open C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\Development\JavaDevelopment\HelloCompute\bin\rsObj\armeabi-v7a\mono.o: No such file or directory
> [2014-01-06 20:45:09 - HelloCompute] C:\android_sdk_windows\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\mipsel-linux-android-ld.exe: cannot find C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\Development\JavaDevelopment\HelloCompute\bin\rsObj\mips\mono.o: No such file or directory
> [2014-01-06 20:45:10 - HelloCompute] C:\android_sdk_windows\android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\i686-linux-android-ld.exe: error: cannot open C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\Development\JavaDevelopment\HelloCompute\bin\rsObj\x86\mono.o: No such file or directory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this issue at least for a time! I redownloaded the ADT package from the official website and replaced my build-tools (from 30.12.13) with the "new" ones (from 23.10.13). This helped me creating the *.o and *.so files. As a result, I guess that there really was a bug in build-tools 19.0.1 from december 2013...

Comment: There is a bug in the December tools, but downgrading is not a great solution. A new version of the SDK should be available soon.

Comment: so what else do you recommend for the meantime? I actually don't see any other chance...

Answer (score 1):

what does your `project.properties` look like? it seems like part of your app is expecting the RS support library and that toolchain and other parts are not compiling the support library parts.

Comment: This is my `project.properties`: `target=android-18 renderscript.target=18 renderscript.support.mode=true sdk.buildtools=19.0.1` Nice idea, but still no plan what to do.. As you're from renderscript developement team, do you at least now what `Return code -1073741511` means? @TimMurray